# Dynamic cell size depending on the size of Image fetched from URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, autoresize

**INFO:**

I have `Tableview` which is having cells with `Imageview`.
In that Imageview, I am fetching Different images from imgURL...

**What I need:**

I need Dynamic height of cell according to the image height fetched from imgURL.

> NOTE: I am not using auto layout, but i am using auto resizing.

**What i did till now:**

I have used asynchronous Image loading in ImageView. ( by `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"`)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    HomePostCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[HomePostCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:strIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImgURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"postPlaceholder"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (!error) {

    }];


    return cell;
}
```

[image: right now screen of tableview]

Is there any solution for this? or can we use auto layout only for cell resizing?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this [category](https://github.com/foundry/UIImageMetadata)

Comment: can u provide the way how to use this in my case

Comment: The category can fetch image metadata aka EXIF which contains information about image resolution, so you can get the image size before you download the image, and supply to you cell size.

Comment: this will be complicated unless server sends the size in advance. Otherwise you will have to download and then get the height. Afterwards, reload the table.

Comment: @Shubhank An image always has EXIF and resolution.

Comment: without downloading the image you cannot get the EXIF nor resolution @iphonic

Comment: @Shubhank Yes you can, try [this link](https://github.com/foundry/UIImageMetadata) here we are just fetching exif/headers of the url, not the whole content.

Comment: @Sam Please try my solution and let me know if u face any issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ideal case, I would normally expect the API to return all images with the same size or a size that can be configured through query string parameters like: `/get_image/?width=400&height=400` etc.

Anyway, the problem here is that, there is no way you can update the height of a cell once it was created and ready to be drawn onto screen (*in other words, once it was returned from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)* unless you reload that cell or the entire table view manually. Luckily for us, `sd_setImageWithURL` works in an asynchronous manner which means you will have the opportunity to call `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPath` once the image has been fetched and stored.

Reloading will cause `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to be called on the reloaded cell so we'll get the correct height this time.

*(Since table view cells are reusable objects, they don't store any information about the data they use in order to configure their UI. Thus, you need to store your images in your view controller, preferably inside an array.)*

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *fetchedImages;
@end

@implementation ViewController
...

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UIImage *image = [self.fetchedImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  if (image) {
    return image.size.height + 1.0; // 1.0 for the separator.
  }
  else {
    return 50.0; // Default value..
  }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return self.fetchedImages.count;
}
```

With all that said, you can do something like the following in `(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ...

  UIImage *image = [self.fetchedImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if (image) {
    // If there is image don't bother fetching the image.
    cell.imageView.image = image;
  }
  else {
    NSURL *imageURL = [self.imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    if (image) {
      [self.fetchedImages replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:image];
      [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
  }];
  return cell;
}
```

Here is the result I ended up:

[image]

You can download the [test project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d552lji6kgxb8nc/AAB7m6oDWCttW2skYB6nwcm2a?dl=0) and play around with it to have a better understanding about what I did above.

Answer (score 1):

this code work with auto resizing, may help you.

```
#define Screen_Width [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
{
    return imageHeight;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NativeStreamAdCell *cell=(NativeStreamAdCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTable"];
        if(cell==nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"NativeStreamAdCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
         [cell.postImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic_feed valueForKey:@"feed_image"]] placeholderImage:cell.postImg.image options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
        //Display image based on size
        UIImage *img = cell.postImg.image;

        int image_width = img.size.width;
        int image_height = img.size.height;
        image_width = Screen_Width;
        image_height = (Screen_Width * img.size.height / img.size.width);
        if(image_width > image_height) {
            image_height = (Screen_Width * image_height / image_width);
        }
        cell.postImg.frame = CGRectMake(cell.postImg.frame.origin.x, cell.postImg.frame.origin.y,
                                     image_width,image_height);

        imageHeight =  CGRectGetMaxY(cell.postImg.frame);
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed [example of Ozgur Vatansever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443575/dynamic-cell-size-depending-on-the-size-of-image-fetched-from-url-in-ios/39444402#39444402) but it flickers when scrolling fast.

Even [this](http://candycode.io/dynamic-uitableview-height-for-downloaded-images/) didn't help.

I found that `[self.tableView reloadData]` works instead of

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

OR

```
[weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
[weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
```